# Kotlin - How to create an alias function of RxJava flatmap()?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I tried to create an alias function to `Flowable.flatmap()` as follow, but compile error.

```
fun <T, R> Flowable<T>.then(mapper: Function<T, Publisher<R>>): Flowable<R> {
  return flatMap(mapper)
}
```

The error is : **One type argument expected for interface `Function<out R>` defined in kotlin**

Have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flatMap` takes a `java.util.function.Function`, the actually error is you didn't import the `java.util.function.Function` in your Kotlin file, but I don't suggest you use the [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) functions because you can't take advantage of the [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) to use the lambda directly from the Kotlin code which defined with [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) functional interface as parameter type.

You should replace `Function` with `Function1`, since the `Function` interface is a Kotlin [marker interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540820/if-a-marker-interface-does-not-have-any-methods-how-does-it-work) only. for example:

```
//                                  v--- use the `Function1<T,R>` here
fun <T, R> Flowable<T>.then(mapper: Function1<T, Publisher<R>>): Flowable<R> {
    return flatMap(mapper)
}
```

**OR** use the Kotlin [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) as below, for example:

```
//                                      v--- use the Kotlin function type here  
fun <T, R> Flowable<T>.then(mapper: (T) -> Publisher<R>): Flowable<R> {
    return flatMap(mapper)
}
```